# AWS IAM - how to check user's permissions roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, federated-identity

I have our AWS Setup, everything is via SAML Federation (no IAM users). Users are added to groups in AD and granted roles, login via SSO.

My issue is **how do I check a a specific users permissions/roles**. Our AD granters say they have set it up, user complains it does not work.

Is there a way to actually test, can the AWS Simulator help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the AWS IAM Policy Simulator to find out if a principal is allowed to execute specific actions, and if the action is explicitly denied by a particular policy that is not directly attached to the principal, e.g. a permission boundary, a service control policy, a resource policy, etc.).

You can learn more here: [Testing IAM policies with the IAM policy simulator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html)

Comment: 1. Simulator - based on the Federation scenario - can I test it only for a self/logged in user or any user (we do not have IAM users).  2. Is there a CLI way to do this - understand Simulator/API also exists.

Comment: You can check roles in the simulator, too.

Answer (score 0):

We're using a NodeJS script to quickly validate user permissions via [`IAM.SimulatePrincipalPolicy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_SimulatePrincipalPolicy.html). You can validate permissions for yourself or another user to which you have access:

https://gist.github.com/AnthumChris/cbfeeeec231394b7b369ea94eabcb812